# C# parse array inside JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have this JSON:

```
{
   "Date": "3/6/17",
   "Place": "MyPlace",
   "Questions": [{
       "Category": "",
       "Question": "???",
       "Answer": ""
   }, {
       "Category": "",
       "Question": "??? ",
       "Answer": ""
   }, {
       "Category": "",
       "Question": "???",
       "Answer": ""
   }]
}
```

I want to parse this JSON and get the array inside it as a list.
Using `var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JToken>>(jsonString);` doesn't work because the thing as a whole isn't an array, only inside it there is an array.
So how do I do this in C#?

Comment: Create some C# classes that match your models, and deserialize into those.

Comment: @Amy Can you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: @amitairos there are *lots* of examples of doing that.  the Newtonsoft documentation has plenty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the following classes:

```
public class Question
{

    [JsonProperty("Category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Question")]
    public string Question { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Answer")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionsDatePlace
{
    [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Place")]
    public string Place { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Questions")]
    public IList<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

and then desrialize your json as below:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuestionsDatePlace>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, without creating additional classes it's:

```
dynamic json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
var list = json["Questions"];
```

If you need to cast the result as a sequence of JToken objects then do this.

```
dynamic json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
var list = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)json["Questions"]).Select(q => new JToken()
{
    Category = q["Category"],
    Question = q["Question"],
    Answer = q["Answer"]
});
```

For the record, this required adding the assembly **System.Web.Extensions** in `References` node of `Solution Explorer`.